# Google Charts: In Material Line Chart point size is not working

Tags: svg, charts, google-visualization

In the following code for **Material Line Chart** the `pointSize` attribute is not working as expected. While in the documentation it is written that the default value of the `pointSize` is `0` and setting it to something bigger than `0` will make it visible, but its not working in my case.

**In short I want to make the points visible on my chart but its not working.**

### [Jsfiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/90dvrmh4/)

```js
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');
      data.addRows([
        [1, 0, 0, 41.8],
        [2, 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3, 25.4, 57, 25.7],
        [4, 11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5, 11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6, 8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
        [7, 7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
        [8, 12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9, 16.9, 0, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11, 5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
        [12, 6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
        [13, 4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
        [14, 4.2, 6.2, 3.4],
        [15, 4.5, 5.9, 41.8],
        [16, 30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [17, 25.4, 57, 25.7],
        [18, 11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [19, 11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [20, 8.8, 13.6, 7.7],
        [21, 7.6, 12.3, 9.6],
        [22, 12.3, 29.2,10.6],
        [23, 16.9, 0, 14.8],
        [24, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [25, 5.3, 7.9, 4.7],
        [26, 6.6, 8.4, 5.2],
        [27, 4.8, 6.3, 3.6],
        [28, 30.2, 45.2, 25.4],
        [29, 40.2, 25.2, 36.4],
        [30, 25.2, 35.2, 30.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)',
        },
        pointSize: 20,
        pointShape: 'square',
        width: 600,
        height: 400
      };
      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

Comment: there are [several options that are not supported](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) by _material_ charts, including `pointSize` -- recommend using _core_ instead, with the following option --> `theme: 'material'`

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat, it was helpful.

Comment: @WhiteHat can you elaborate a bit what you mean with `core`? can you link an example?

Comment: @linqu -- core meaning classic or non-material chart --> material line chart = `google.charts.Line` where classic line chart = `google.visualization.LineChart`

Comment: @WhiteHat does the theme support top y axes?

Comment: classic charts do not support top x-axis, but you can manually move the labels on the chart's `'ready'` event, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784953/how-to-start-y-axis-points-starts-from-top-in-google-charts/60794486#60794486)...